# Find a conformal bijection from $\{z : |z| > 1, Im$ $z < 5\}$ onto an annulus centered at the origin.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble doing conformal map problems.  Any suggestions on how to do this problem?  Thanks.

Find a conformal bijection from $\{z : |z| > 1, Im$ $z < 5\}$ onto an annulus centered at the origin.

Comment: Start by mapping $\{z:\operatorname{Im} z < 5\}$ conformally to a disk (centered at the origin). Can you see how you could then proceed?

Comment: Find the points (there are 2 of them) whose reflection wrt the unit circle is equal to the reflection wrt the line $Im\ z=5$. Then send one of them to $0$ and the other to $\infty$ with $(z-a)/(z-b)$ ($a,b$ are the 2 points). That's it.

Comment: What does reflection wrt the unit circle mean?

Comment: Inversion, i.e. $z\mapsto 1/\bar z$

Comment: okay...so how do I know the map you described works?

Comment: If you are going to post 38 questions and add bounties to them, it may be time to register (set a password). Otherwise your account will last only as long as a cookie in your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boundary already consists of two circles (counting a line as a circle). We just have to make them concentric with a suitable Möbius transformation. The inner circle $|z|=1$ looks good already; let's keep it that way. Also, since both circles are symmetric about the imaginary axis, our transformation can be symmetric too:  it will map the imaginary axis to itself. So, it will be
$$f(z) = \frac{z-ib}{1+ibz}$$
where $b\in(-1,1)$ is a real number to be determined. The image of $\operatorname{Im}z=5$ is symmetric about the imaginary axis; to find it, we just need to know where it crosses the axis. This is where:
$$f(5i)=\frac{5i-ib}{1-5b} = \frac{5-b}{1-5b} i, \quad f(\infty) = \frac{1}{ib} = -\frac{1}{b}i$$
These two points are endpoints of a diameter of the image. And we want the center of the image to be zero, so
$$\frac{5-b}{1-5b} = \frac{1}{b}$$
from where $b=5-2\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: Here is another question in complex analysis that has been answered (and awarded with half a bounty, therefore I conclude) but not in a satisfactory manner:
[a problem in application of conformal mappings](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820189/a-problem-in-application-of-conformal-mappings) .
The gist of the question IMO is how to find a _heuristics_. As the OP says: "_Obtain_ the complex potential". I wasn't capable to answer the question in that sense and I wonder if you are.